# How can I turn a pandas dataframe with columns with similar names into rows?

Tags: python, pandas

For instance, I have the below dataframe[image]

That I would like to turn into something like:

```
Timetsamp     | invoice_number | invoice_amount

10/14/2019    |   20565116     |  101.09

10/14/2019    |   20617023     |  505.57

10/15/2019    |   20600496     |  503.2

10/15/2019    |   20582306     |  501.11
```

Comment: Do you want to drop the columns?

Comment: Yes, i think he wants to drop them and then join them at the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# timestamp dataframe
timestamp = df[['Timestamp']]

# stores the new dataframe with timestamp and invoices
new_df = pd.DataFrame():

# iterate through the cols in original dataframe in steps of 2
for c in range(1,len(df.columns),2):

    # get the column invoice number and amount
    temp = df[[df.columns[c],df.columns[c+1]]
    # concat with the timestamp
    temp = pd.concat([timestamp, temp], axis = 1)
    # make a bigger dataframe
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp], axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
group = df.set_index('timestamp').T.groupby(df.columns[1:])
df = pd.concat([grp.T.stack().droplevel(1).rename(idx).to_frame() for idx, grp in group], 1)
```